# Click button short vs long button presses Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am using the [clickbutton](https://code.google.com/p/clickbutton/wiki/Usage) library from Arduous and am having some problems implementing it. As it stand now the code just runs the servo clockwise and I'm not sure what I did wrong. Basically I want the servo if pressed for a short period of time to move according to an exponential function, and if pressed according to a long period of time to move at a regular pace.

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include "ClickButton.h"

Servo myservo; // create servo object to control a servo

// CONSTANTS

// PINS
const int crServo = 12; // sets pin 12 as servo
const int buttonPinCW = 2; // sets pin 2 as button; CW => clockwise => FOCUS FAR
const int buttonPinCC = 3; // sets pin 3 as button; CC => counterclockwise => FOCUS NEAR
const int ledPinB = 4; // sets pin 10 as LED
const int ledPinG = 5; // sets pin 10 as LED
const int ledPinR = 6; // sets pin 10 as LED

const int t = 1;  // slow down

// SERVO PROPERTIES
const int crSpeedDefault = 100; // is the stay still position, motor should not turn
const int crSpeedCW = 107; // turns the motor full speed clockwise
const int crSpeedCC = 87; // turns the motor full speed counter-clockwise

// SET BUTTON STATES
ClickButton buttonCW(buttonPinCW, LOW);
ClickButton buttonCC(buttonPinCC, LOW);

void setup()
{
  myservo.attach(crServo); // attaches the servo on pin 12 to the servo object
  //pinMode (buttonPinCW, INPUT); // sets button as input
  //pinMode (buttonPinCC, INPUT); // sets button as input
  pinMode (ledPinB, OUTPUT); // sets led as output
  pinMode (ledPinG, OUTPUT); // sets led as output
  pinMode (ledPinR, OUTPUT); // sets led as output
  myservo.write(crSpeedDefault); // default servo to crSpeedDefault
  startup();
}

int startup() {
  //blinker(2, ledPinB);
  //blinker(1, ledPinG);
  //blinker(1, ledPinR);
}

void blinker(int count, int pin) {
  for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
  {
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  buttonCW.Update();
  buttonCC.Update();
  int buttonCWClicks = 0;
  int buttonCCClicks = 0;
  if (buttonCW.clicks != 0) buttonCWClicks = buttonCW.clicks;
  if (buttonCC.clicks != 0) buttonCCClicks = buttonCC.clicks;
  //buttonStateCW = digitalRead(buttonPinCW);
  //buttonStateCC = digitalRead(buttonPinCC);
  // clockwise rotation
  if (buttonCW.depressed == true) {
    if (buttonCWClicks == 1) {
      digitalWrite(ledPinR, HIGH);
      float speed = crSpeedCW;
      Serial.print("CLOCKWISE-ROTATION \n");
      for (int i = 0; i < t * 5; i++) {
        speed += ((float)crSpeedDefault - speed)/ 10;
        Serial.print(speed);
        Serial.print("\n");
        myservo.write((int)speed);
        delay(100);
      }
      myservo.write(crSpeedCW);
    } 
    else if (buttonCWClicks == -1) {
      digitalWrite(ledPinR, HIGH);
      myservo.write(crSpeedCW);
    }
  } 
  else if (buttonCC.depressed == true) {
    if (buttonCCClicks == 1) {
      digitalWrite(ledPinG, HIGH);
      float speed = crSpeedCC;
      Serial.print("COUNTER-CLOCKWISE-ROTATION \n");
      for (int i = 0; i < t * 5; i++) {
        speed += ((float)crSpeedDefault - speed) / 10;
        Serial.print(speed);
        Serial.print("\n");
        myservo.write((int)speed);
        delay(100);
      }
      myservo.write(crSpeedCC);
    } 
    else if (buttonCCClicks == -1) {
      digitalWrite(ledPinR, HIGH);
      myservo.write(crSpeedCW);
    }
  } 
  else {
    myservo.write(crSpeedDefault);
    digitalWrite(ledPinR, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(ledPinG, LOW);     // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  }
}
```